# Webpack served application not handling bundle.js file correctly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, nginx, webpack

I have an application that uses module federation and webpack. Everything is working fine when I deploy the application locally to a nginx docker image. However, when the pipeline runs and I access it from the browser from its dev URL, I can see that the bundle.js and remoteEntry.js files have the content of index.html. So my page is rendered blank. Here is a screenshot, side by side, of both local and deployed applications sources:

[image]

This is my first time using webpack, so I don't know what exactly is missing. Below is my webpack.config:

```
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const { ModuleFederationPlugin } = require("webpack").container;

const path = require("path");
const deps = require("./package.json").dependencies;

const htmlPlugin = new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
  template: "./public/index.html",
  filename: "./index.html",
});

module.exports = {
  mode: "development",
  entry: "./src/index.tsx",
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".ts", ".tsx", ".js"],
    modules: [path.resolve(__dirname, "src"), "node_modules"],
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
    filename: "bundle.js",
    publicPath: "mfe-prompt/", //This line only exists on the pipe. Locally, I have the exact same file without this single line
  },
  devServer: {
    static: path.join(__dirname, "dist"),
    port: 3000,
    headers: {
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
    },
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(ts|tsx|js)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: "ts-loader",
      },
      {
        test: /\.s[ac]ss$/i,
        use: ["style-loader", "css-loader", "sass-loader"],
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    htmlPlugin,
    new ModuleFederationPlugin({
      name: "prompt_mfe",
      filename: "remoteEntry.js",
      exposes: {
        "./Prompt": "./src/containers/Prompt/Prompt.tsx",
      },
      shared: {
        ...deps,
        react: { singleton: true, eager: true, requiredVersion: deps.react },
        "react-dom": {
          singleton: true,
          eager: true,
          requiredVersion: deps["react-dom"],
        },
        "react-router-dom": {
          singleton: true,
          eager: true,
          requiredVersion: deps["react-router-dom"],
        },
        "@dds/react": {
          singleton: true,
          eager: true,
          requiredVersion: deps["@dds/react"],
        },
        "prop-types": {
          singleton: true,
          eager: true,
          requiredVersion: deps["prop-types"],
        },
      },
    }),
  ],
};
```

Don't know if its useful, but this is my nginx conf:

```
worker_processes 4;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    server {
        listen 80;
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        
        location / {
            root /usr/share/nginx/html;
            index index.html;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }
    }
}
```